# How to add shared and local parameter in same test case in Azure Test Plans?

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

While creating test cases in Azure Test Plan, I want to add shared as well as local parameter for test data.
Currently when I add shared parameters, it is not allowing to add value to local parameters.

Created shared parameters and added to test case.
Created local parameter and try to add value for that parameter.

If we add local parameter first and then click on Add a shared parameters set, message "Changing local parameters to shared parameters deletes any local parameter values. Do you want to continue?" displayed.

If we add shared parameter first and then try to add local parameter then it is now allowing to assign value for that local parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Test Plans.

Go to any test plan and create a **New Test Case** OR Directly Click on **New Test Case Button.**

After clicking on new test case , you will be taken to new window.
In **Steps Field**, You will be having 2nd icon **insert shared parameter**
Choose any shared parameter set among the list and Click on **Insert Shared Parameter Button.**

Now in the steps field ,first step will be the name of shared parameter in bold format.
In that second step you can add you own step (i.e Local Parameter)
Shown Below

[image]